# Hide debug message from console log

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm using Instrument's UIAutomation program to build automated iOS tests and running them from the command line. I want to use the console output as a test report, but I would prefer not to see *every single tap and drag* and so forth, which are logged as 'debug' messages.  I've checked the [UIALogger class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIALoggerClassReference/UIALogger/UIALogger.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIALogger/logMessage), the [Instruments documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html), and Google searched this issue, but can't find a way to suppress these or run with an even-less-than-non-verbose option.

**Question:** Is there any way to hide or disable the debug messages coming from UIALogger in the Instruments command line options?

Answer (score 3):

Run these commands from the terminal to disable the messages:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.InstrumentsCLI UIAVerboseLogging -int 4096
defaults write com.apple.dt.Instruments UIAVerboseLogging -int 4096
```

Those command alter a setting in the preferences of instruments to turn off verbose logging. You can turn them back on with these commands:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.InstrumentsCLI UIAVerboseLogging
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Instruments UIAVerboseLogging
```

I mention these settings and more command line stuff about UI Automation in [my book](http://pragprog.com/book/jptios/test-ios-apps-with-ui-automation), for further reference.

Comment: This still seems to trigger the tap and swipe action messages such as the following: `+0000 Debug: target.tap(...` Any idea how to kill these "Debug" messages triggered even if verbose logging was never set?

Comment: This **does** disable the debug messages in the Instruments 'Editor Log,' but they still seem to display when running from the terminal.

Comment: Crap. Sounds like Apple may have broken this. What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using version 5.1.1.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what's going on then. I'd suggest filing a Radar with Apple. Their next Xcode beta will be released in a month at WWDC. I'm curious if they will address this.

Comment: That helped me, but it might be configurable somehow? not to execute hack commands in terminal... no?

Comment: Alas, no. Apple has not exposed a configuration setting for this other than the Terminal commands.